# Automatically adding <div class="ExternalClassE7D56B8D72FF4453B3F162CE43ABBF0A"> in field in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

When I created content for custom list. It is "gegtege". After I create a asp:textbox that calling this field and display `"<div class="ExternalClassE7D56B8D72FF4453B3F162CE43ABBF0A">"` in `txtComment.Text`.

I don't understand and how to remove it?

```
SPWeb webObj = SPContext.Current.Web;
            //SPFolder ManagerSubMainList = webObj.Folders["ManagerSubMainList"];
            //SPFolder AssignerMainList = webObj.Folders["AssignerMainList "];
            SPList listContract = webObj.Lists["MainList"];
            SPListItem thisItem = null;
            if (getId() > 0)
            {
                thisItem = listContract.GetItemById(getId());
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisItem["Title"].ToString()))
                {
                    txtTitle.Text = thisItem["Title"].ToString();
                }
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisItem["Comment"].ToString()))
                {
                    txtComment.Text = thisItem["Comment"].ToString();
                }


                //thisItem.Update();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list, make sure that the Multiple lines of text column setting is set to `plain text`

- Go to list setting
- click on the column name.
- Beside `Additional Column Settings`, Check `Plain text`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
SPWeb webObj = SPContext.Current.Web;
//SPFolder ManagerSubMainList = webObj.Folders["ManagerSubMainList"];
//SPFolder AssignerMainList = webObj.Folders["AssignerMainList "];
SPList listContract = webObj.Lists["MainList"];
SPListItem thisItem = null;
if (getId() > 0)
{
    thisItem = listContract.GetItemById(getId());
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisItem["Title"].ToString()))
    {
        txtTitle.Text = thisItem["Title"].ToString();
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisItem["Comment"].ToString()))
    {
        string comment = thisItem["Comment"].ToString();
        txtComment.Text = SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText(comment, comment.Length);       
    }

    //thisItem.Update();
}
```

Reference - [SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sphttputility.convertsimplehtmltotext.aspx)